# Why does React's SyntheticEvent not work in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) and I've tried to stop my form with `e.preventDefault()` but it didn't work. I finally found a *solution* to my problem, I replaced `e.preventDefault()` by `e.nativeEvent.preventDefault()`.

I want to know why React's event(SyntheticEvent) did not work.
Furthermore, what is the difference between `e.preventDefault()` and `e.nativeEvent.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow .
Please provide your code, along with error and your expected result
please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
See [How do I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In React, events are handled using **SyntheticEvents**, which are a cross-browser wrapper around the **native events**. SyntheticEvents aim to provide a consistent and simple interface for handling events in React, regardless of the underlying browser.
[Read more on React events.](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

`e.preventDefault()` is the method for preventing the default behavior of an event in *React's SyntheticEvent system*. In your case it is not working when trying to stop a form submission.

You should then access the underlying native event using `e.nativeEvent` and call `preventDefault()` on that. The reason this works is because the `preventDefault()` method on the *native event* **directly stops** the default behavior, whereas the `preventDefault()` method on the *SyntheticEvent* only sets a flag to indicate that the default behavior **should be stopped**. The actual stopping of the default behavior is handled by React when it processes the event.